# read a file from last position using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, file-io

My requirement is to read a large file which is being updated continuously using a shell script from cron job. I will read until the last available line and then stop the process. Next time when the cron job starts the job should read from the position where it was last finished. Any suggestions how can I do this in shell script.

I am using Solaris Unix.

Comment: Save the old file size, and then use `tail -c +$filesize logfile`.

Comment: Why complicate things with `cron`?  Start a process and have it read to the end of the file and then sleep for some period of time (keeping the file open).  When it wakes up, read more data from the file position it was at when it went to sleep.

Comment: Or pipe `tail -f`, which automates the "read, sleep" cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this one (of course add it in cron):

```
#!/bin/bash

#STAT_FILE=/tmp/stat.tmp
PREV_LINE_STAT=/tmp/prev_last_line.tmp
LINE=$(cat log | wc -l)
LOG=/tmp/log.tmp

if [ -f $PREV_LINE_STAT ]
then
    PREV_LINE=$(cat $PREV_LINE_STAT)
else
    PREV_LINE=0
fi

declare -i LINE_RANGE
LINE_RANGE=$LINE-$PREV_LINE


if [ $LINE_RANGE -lt 0 ]
then
    LINE_RANGE=$LINE
fi

tail -n $LINE_RANGE log > $LOG

COUNT1=$(grep any_word $LOG |wc -l)

echo "-------------------
LINE_RANGE is $LINE_RANGE
-------------------
number of words 
$COUNT1" > test.txt

echo $LINE > $PREV_LINE_STAT

cat test.txt
```

So the main tool there is "tail". Ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: `tail -n` requires the file being read from the start; this may be quite time-consuming since the file is large. Thus, `tail -c` (as Barmar suggested above) might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach as already indicated is to use "tail -f", but assuming that for some reason your program died, you would have to start reading from the beginning and you could not use "tail -f" to continue where it left off.

So the only way would be to write your own C application. It should be easy enough because it is rather simple. You can use the "ftell" to find out where you are located in the data file. Then you will write that result in some other file (a control file) either before you exit your application, or after every reads (if it is critical that you never reprocess a line again).

Once you restart your application, you read that control file, parse the value and use "fseek" to jump where you left off.

If the data file is truncated by some other app, you should also get that app to remove your control file. Otherwise, you will have to find some other way of knowing that the file is new. It could be the "fseek" you read is greater than the current "ftell" which would indicate the file is smaller than it was, but that would not cover all eventualities.

You could investigate "fstat" and use the creation time of the data file to see if it is newer than the creation time you would have saved in the control file **OR** if you can, I would write a date/time stamp in the file's first line, and write that in the control file too. When the app restarts, if the first line timestamp does not match the control file timestamp, you read from the beginning. Otherwise the "fseek" should bring you to the correct location.